# VBScript Importing .txt file to .xlsx file

Tags: excel, text, vbscript

I use this *VBScript* code for trying import on excel file *output.xlsx* the text file *input.txt*

This is text file *input.txt*

[image]

This is excel file *output.xlsx*

[image]

This code don't have error but the *output.xlsx* is empty.

How to do resolve this ?

```
ExcelFilePath = "D:\xlsx\output.xlsx"

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.visible = True
Set objWB = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath)
Set SheetObject = objWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")

TextFile = "D:\txt\input.txt"

Set TextRead = objFSO.OpenTextFile(TextFile, ForReading)

row = 2

With SheetObject
    .Cells(1, 1).Value = "CO"
    .Cells(1, 2).Value = "Sequence No"
    .Cells(1, 3).Value = "Transaction Date"
    .Cells(1, 4).Value = "Contract No"
    .Cells(1, 5).Value = "Creation Date"
    .Cells(1, 6).Value = "Source"
    .Cells(1, 7).Value = "Record"
    .Cells(1, 8).Value = "Amount"
    .Cells(1, 9).Value = "Source"
    .Cells(1, 10).Value = "Filler"

    Do Until TextRead.AtEndOfStream
        Line = TextRead.ReadLine

        .Cells(row, 1).Value = Mid(Line, 1, 1)
        .Cells(row, 2).Value = Mid(Line, 2, 9)
        .Cells(row, 3).Value = Mid(Line, 11, 19)
        .Cells(row, 4).Value = Mid(Line, 30, 1)
        .Cells(row, 5).Value = Mid(Line, 31, 8)
        .Cells(row, 6).Value = Mid(Line, 39, 9)
        .Cells(row, 7).Value = Mid(Line, 48, 17)
        .Cells(row, 8).Value = Mid(Line, 65, 2)
        .Cells(row, 9).Value = Mid(Line, 67, 334)
        .Cells(row, 10).Value = Mid(Line, 67, 334)

        row = row + 1
    Loop
End With

objWB.Save
objWB.Close
objExcel.Quit
```

**#Edit 01**

Many thanks for help, I have tried this new code, without success.

I don't have error on the script but the XLSX file is empty

```
ExcelFilePath = "D:\xlsx\output.xlsx"

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.visible = True
Set objWB = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath)
Set SheetObject = objWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")

TextFile = "D:\txt\input.txt"

Set TextRead = objFSO.OpenTextFile(TextFile, ForReading)

row = 2

With SheetObject
    .Cells(1, 1).Value = "CO"
    .Cells(1, 2).Value = "Sequence No"
    .Cells(1, 3).Value = "Transaction Date"
    .Cells(1, 4).Value = "Contract No"
    .Cells(1, 5).Value = "Creation Date"
    .Cells(1, 6).Value = "Source"
    .Cells(1, 7).Value = "Record"
    .Cells(1, 8).Value = "Amount"
    .Cells(1, 9).Value = "Source"
    .Cells(1, 10).Value = "Filler"

    Do Until TextRead.AtEndOfStream
        Line = TextRead.ReadLine

        aLines = split(TextFile.ReadAll, vbnewline)
        For irow = 1 To UBound(aLines) + 1
            aline = split(aLines(irow-1), "|")
            For icol = 1 To UBound(aline) + 1
               SheetObject.Cells(irow, icol).value = aline(icol-1)
            Next
        Next

        row = row + 1
    Loop
End With

objWB.Save
objWB.Close
objExcel.Quit
```

**#Edit 02**

```
With SheetObject
    Do Until TextRead.AtEndOfStream
        strLine = Trim(TextRead.ReadLine)

        If (strLine <> "") Then
            arrValues = Split(strLine, "|")
            For irow = 1 To UBound(arrValues) + 1
                For icol = 1 To UBound(arrValues) + 1
                    SheetObject.Cells(irow, icol).value = arrValues(icol-1)
                Next
             Next
        End If
    Loop
End With
```

Comment: Your input file seems to be pipe-delimited data, so the recommended way would be to import the data into Excel directly (see linked question at the top of your question). If the input file contains non-tabular information I would suggest to remove that information in a preparatory step before the import (write modified data to temp text file).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Many thanks for help, please see **#Edit 01** in my first question. Now I don't have error on the script but the XLSX file is empty.

Comment: May I suggest that you take an actual look at the *answers* to the linked question (my answer specifically)?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I have see the linked question and your answer specifically but does not seem to be my case. If it is not a problem you can view my **Edit #02** in my first question ? The excel file is compiled from the txt file splitting by pipeline but it is an infinite loop. The text file contains 34 rows ... but import infinite rows.... and delete rows header

Comment: In case that wasn't clear enough before: don't do what you're doing. Let Excel import your text file. Prep the text file beforehand if needed. Do not "manually" copy values from textfile to Excel. That will perform poorly.